# How to use css shaders with google chrome canary

Tags: css, shader

I wish to use css shaders with Chrome Canary.
However I could not find #enable-css-shaders in chrome://flags in Version 37.0.2035.2 canary.
is css shaders removed from flags?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I couldn't find this either. It does not appear to be under chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features either.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Umm... Chrome might stop the support for the css shaders, but no one makes mention it. It's strange...

Comment: This function has been removed from Chrome.

Read this thread for more: https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-dev/2014-January/026098.html